# Pointer will not work in printf()

Tags: c, pointers, printf

Having an issue with printing a pointer out. Every time I try and compile the program below i get the following error:

```
pointers.c:11: warning: format ‘%p’ expects type ‘void *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int *’
```

I'm obviously missing something simple here, but from other examles of similar code that I have seen, this should be working.

Here's the code, any help would be great!

```
#include <stdio.h>

    int main(void)
    {
       int x = 99;
       int *pt1;

       pt1 = &x;

       printf("Value at p1: %d\n", *pt1);
       printf("Address of p1: %p\n", pt1);

       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: The warning description seems just fine to me. Cast it to void before sending it to printf. instead of pt1, (void*)pt1

Comment: Try adding an ampersand to pt1 and see if that works.

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Simply cast your int pointer to a void one:

```
printf( "Address of p1: %p\n", ( void * )pt1 );
```

Your code is safe, but you are compiling with the `-Wformat` warning flag, that will type check the calls to `printf()` and `scanf()`.

Comment: Oh OK. I'm new to C and hadn't learned to distinguish between compiler message types until now. Thanks.

Comment: This behavior was determined as valid by gcc developers, see http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=26542

See also a detailed explanation by Jonathan Leffler: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-address

Answer (score 10):

Note that you get a simple warning. Your code will **probably** execute as expected.

The `"%p"` conversion specifier to printf expects a `void*` argument; `pt1` is of type `int*`.

The warning is good because `int*` and `void*` may, on strange implementations, have different sizes or bit patterns *or something*.

Convert the `int*` to a `void*` with a cast ...

```
printf("%p\n", (void*)pt1);
```

... and all will be good, even on strange implementations.

Comment: Even if they have the same size, they may be conveyed to the called function differently under a strange calling convention.

Comment: Thanks @caf, answer reviewed to cover **ALL** cases :)

Answer (score 2):

In this case, the compiler is just a bit overeager with the warnings. Your code is perfectly safe, you can optionally remove the warning with:

```
printf("Address of p1: %p\n", (void *) pt1);
```

Answer (score 1):

The message says it all, but it's just a warning not an error per se:

```
printf("Address of p1: %p\n", (void*)pt1);
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked just fine for me:

```
printf("Pointer address: %p.", pxy);
```

You don't need to cast it as anything, unless you wanted to...