# Simple test of malloc and free with int pointer causes double free or corruption error

Tags: c, testing, malloc, free

To learn more about pointers I wrote just a simple test function which creates a pointer, allocates space ande after some output on the shell the space shall be freed.

```
void main() {
  int *p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));
  int a = 42;
  printf("p: %x\n", p);
  printf("*p: %d\n", *p);
  printf("a: %s\n", a);
  printf("&a: %x\n", &a);
  p = &a;
  printf("p: %x\n", p);
  printf("*p: %x\n", *p);

  //Until now everything works as expected
  free(p); //ERROR
  // printf("p: %x\n", p); // Shall cause error, because space was freed
  // printf("*p: %x\n", *p); // Shall cause error, because space was freed
}
```

At first runs everything was ok. free(p) caused no error. Then I tried the same test with a struct and got the double free error. "Ok, maybe I do something wrong, lets go to the start", I thought and Ctrl+Z everything to this one above, like it was before. Now I still get this error. Why? Thats a newbie question, I know. The code above you can find everywhere in the web as a simple demonstration of malloc and free. Like here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/
Hope, someone can tell me what I do wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The pointer passed to [`free()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/free) *must* be returned from a previous call to `malloc()` (or `calloc()` or `realloc()`). This is not the case as `p` has the address of `a` after:

```
p = &a;
```

and `p` is then passed to `free()` causing undefined behaviour.

Note that in the example on page linked in the question nowhere is the pointer being reassigned after the call to any of the dynamic allocation functions.

---

The comment `"Shall cause error, because space was freed"` in the following code snippet is incorrect:

```
free(p); //ERROR
// printf("p: %x\n", p); // Shall cause error, because space was freed
```

as it is safe to print the address of a pointer, regardless of whether the memory it has been associated with has been `free()` or not. It *is* an error if you attempt to access memory that has been `free()`d, so this comment is correct:

```
// printf("*p: %x\n", *p); // Shall cause error, because space was freed
```

because `p` is being deferenced and an attempt to read `free()`d memory is occurring.

---

This is an error:

```
printf("a: %s\n", a); /* Must be '%d' as 'a' is an 'int'. */
```

Note that:

```
printf("p: %x\n", p);
```

is also undefined behaviour: use `%p` format specifier for pointers. See [Correct format specifier to print pointer (address)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-address)

---

[Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: Ah, that's what I overseen completely. So free tries to deallocate the space of a, which is on the stack and not in the heap. And moreover the original allocated space is still there and not freed and I can't point to him, right?

Comment: @PhantomasPhantom, correct. The assignment causes a memory leak also.

Comment: Thats something what we didn't learn explicitely. Thanks a lot for helping. I've been testing this for hours. Now I understand.

Comment: @PhantomasPhantom, no. `free()` does not (and cannot) set the pointer to `NULL`. It just releases the memory the pointer was pointing to.

Comment: (And don't set the pointer to `NULL` yourself after `free`ing, unless you have some specific code in mind that will be checking it. That's a *very* bad habit to get into.)

Comment: Once again. Thanks. I've learned here more about pointers as in the lessons.

Comment: Well, a bit strange. If I free a struct, the old data is still there, what is normal because it wasnt overidden by something else. But when I used the int pointer the value after freeing was 0 and not the original one.

Comment: @PhantomasPhantom, it is [undefined behaviour](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Comment: Oh, one more of C's inconsequences^^ But after freeing the content of free memory isn't relevant. But nice to know

Comment: @hmjd Didnt knew that it chooses the answer that shall be the main one. thought of it as kinda like-button :D and clicked in the second answer too^^

Answer (score 0):

```
void main() {
  int *p = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));   // here is error number one.
                                         // you casted your fresh malloc'd int
                                         // to an int*
                                         // which is not what you want to do
                                         // get rid of the cast you don't need it.

   // here is where your problem continues.
  int a = 42;   // this variable A was created on the stack not the heap!!
                //you cant free this, which is what you are doing below.
  printf("p: %x\n", p);
  printf("*p: %d\n", *p);
  printf("a: %s\n", a);
  printf("&a: %x\n", &a);

  p = &a; // this is a correct statement. 
          // you getting the address of var a
          // and making pointer p point to A's contents.
  printf("p: %x\n", p);
  printf("*p: %x\n", *p);

  //Until now everything works as expected
  free(p); //ERROR: here you are trying to free var A 
           // but you cant because it wasnt dynamically allocated.
  // printf("p: %x\n", p); // Shall cause error, because space was freed
  // printf("*p: %x\n", *p); // Shall cause error, because space was freed
}
```

hope this helps a bit. 
I highly recommend that you read CH 5 on pointer in K&R(Kernegie and Richie) C programming language book.
its really short and you can probly find it free online somewhere. in fact i recommond that  you read the whole book. best c book out there.
remember you can only free what you malloced (remember each malloc gives you blocks in memory from the heap)

Comment: The casting seems to be kinda thing of taste. Some say "no, never cast", others say "cast!"
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/MEM02-C.+Immediately+cast+the+result+of+a+memory+allocation+function+call+into+a+pointer+to+the+allocated+type