# How to Print Pointers in c?

Tags: c, pointers

Can someone please explain to me why this code gives a Segmentation Fault:

```
char string[] = "this is a string";
char * string2 = "this is another string";
printf("%s\n",string );
printf("%s\n",  string2);
printf("string[2]= %s, string2 = %s\n", string[2], &string2 );
```

It also gives the same error when I try to print

```
*string2 or *string2[2] or &string2[2]
```

I am really confused about this, likewise examples I see on websites seem to print but not this one.

Comment: You probably want to take a look at this question: [Correct format specifier to print pointer (address)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9053658/1298153)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first two are fine but in the last one you probably want:

```
printf("string[2]= %c, string2 = %p\n", string[2], (void *)&string2 );
                    ^             ^
```

You are getting a segmentation fault because you are tricking `printf` into interpreting a small integer (`string[2]`) as a pointer (that's what `%s` expects).

Comment: @zubergu That's what `%p` wants: a `void *`, not just any type of pointer. It probably makes no difference on most machines, but it's good to follow the rules.

Comment: @zubergu No. In first place, because "implicit cast" is an oxymoron, casts are explicit by definition. Second, if you meant "implicit conversion", that doesn't happen either -- `printf()` is not magic. Nor is the compiler. Type conversion rules don't change based on random strings (the `printf()` conversion specifier in this case).

Answer (score 0):

```
char * string2 = "this is another string";
```

declaration causes `string2` point to `t` (first character of string) and that doesn't mean `*string2` is entire string (On derefrencing `string2`),i.e, `"this is another string"`. If you will try to print `*string2` with `%s`, it will cause segmentation fault but with `%c` it will print `t`.
To print a pointer use `%p` specifier.

Comment: By that logic, there is no type in C that can "point to the string". I 'm not sure what your point is.

Comment: A "pointer to a string" is by definition a pointer to the string's first character; the term is defined in the C standard, 7.1.1 paragraph 1. (In the absence of that definition, a "pointer to a string" would not necessarily be meaningful, since a "string" is a data layout, not a type.)

Comment: @Jon Apart from Keith's excellent explanation, what if I told you there were pointers-to-array in C? `char (*arrptr)[10] = &some_char_array;`

Comment: @H2CO3: You would not be telling me anything new, plus I don't see what that has to do with the declaration "causes `string2` to point to `t`".

Comment: @Jon: a string is an array. If you want to "point to a string" instead of just "pointing to the first character of a string", then you use a pointer-to-array, which points to the **entire string,** by definition. (Yeah, I respond to nitpicking with nitpicking.)

Comment: @H2CO3: I 'm sorry to disappoint you, but "A string is a contiguous sequence of characters terminated by and including the first null
character", not "an array" as you say -- arrays are something entirely different, plus there are layman's counter-examples that you can think of yourself if you stop nitpicking.

Comment: @Jon Um no. Then how do you explain the fact that string literals have type `char [N + 1]` (where `N` is the length of the string)?

Comment: @H2CO3: I explain it by saying "string literal != string". If you argue because you believe this answer has merit, please upvote it (though I see you have not done so -- why?). And please stop wasting my time.

Comment: @Jon "If you argue because you believe this answer has merit, please upvote it" - I don't upvote this answer because it's not correct. However, this answer being incorrect does not in itself mean automatically that you are correct -- you aren't.