# C Pointer Location, Decimal and Hexadecimal

Tags: c, pointers, hex, decimal

I am trying to learn how to display the pointer value in decimal and hexadecimal. below you can see me create a value and try to use a pointer to print out the value and the values location.

Please make the code work correctly so that it prints out the values in decimal and hexadecimal

```
double val= 1;
printf("The value of val : %f\n",val);


double *ptr;
ptr= &val;

printf("dereference *ptr= %f\n", *ptr);

//Display the location of val with and without pointer use in decimal and hex


//decimal
printf("location of val in decimal with ptr is: %p\n",(void *) ptr); 
printf("location of val in decimal without a pointer is: %p\n",(void *) &val ); 

//hexadecimal THIS IS NOT WORKING 
printf("location of val in hex with ptr is: %#x\n", (void *) ptr); 
printf("location of val in hex without a pointer is: %#x\n", (void *) &val );
```

Comment: But what is your question?

Comment: i made edits. basically I need to print the pointer location as a decimal and a hexadecimal and the hexadecimal is not working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `%p` format takes a `void *` and prints it in an implementation-defined format.  If you want to seize control, use the types from `<stdint.h>` and formats from `<inttypes.h>` (first defined in C99):

```
#include <inttypes.h>

printf("Location in decimal:  %" PRIuPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)ptr);
printf("Location in hex:      0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)ptr);
printf("Location in octal     %#" PRIoPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)ptr);
```

Etc.

The `uintptr_t` type (which is nominally optional, but all practical implementations should define it) is an unsigned integer type big enough to hold a pointer to an object (variable; not necessarily big enough to hold a function pointer).  The names such as `PRIuPTR` define the right conversion specifier for the `uintptr_t` type (the value is platform specific).

Note that if you use `<inttypes.h>`, you don't need to include `<stdint.h>`.

Answer (score 1):

C usually returns memory addresses as hexadecimal numbers, so you only need to use %p. As for the decimal representation, you can use type casting:

```
int rand1 = 12, rand2 = 15;

printf("rand1 = %p : rand2 = %p\n\n", &rand1, &rand2); 
// returns hexadecimal value of address

printf("rand1 = %d : rand2 = %d\n\n", (int) &rand1, (int) &rand2);  
// returns decimal value of address
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget to include `#include <inttypes.h>`.

As suggested by the comments, it's better to do this:

```
//hexadecimal
printf("Location in hex:      0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)ptr);
printf("Location in hex:      0x%.8" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)&val);
```

If you feel uncomfortable with the `unitptr_t` cast, then imagine you are casting to an `unsigned int`. It's not the same, but it's something for a start.

For more, read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-address) answer.

Also, you might want to take a look into the [difference](http://www.viva64.com/en/k/0019/) between `%p` and `%x`.

Comment: You're correct using `(uintptr_t)` casts.  You're incorrect not using `PRIxPTR` etc.  Specifically, on a 64-bit Unix system, `%x` is for printing 32-bit (unsigned) integers, but `uintptr_t` is a 64-bit unsigned integer.

Comment: I see Jonathan, thanks for the advice. Happy to learn new things, here is my +1.

Comment: Note that the `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` should not be necessary with a C99 or C11 compiler for standard C.  There seems to have been some confusion a few years ago for C++ compilers.  The C99 standard (but not the C11 standard) has a footnote 182 which says: _182) C++ implementations should define these macros only when `__STDC_FORMAT_MACROS` is defined
before `<inttypes.h>` is included._  That does not apply to C implementations; the macros in `<inttypes.h>` should be defined provided you compile with `-std=c99` or `-std=c11` or the moral equivalents.

Answer (score 0):

For decimal use %lu (long unsigned) instead %p
Also, no need for the (void *) casting with normal printf function

Like this:

```
//decimal
printf("location of val in decimal with ptr is: %lu\n",ptr); 
printf("location of val in decimal without a pointer is: %lu\n",&val );
```

You may use the %p instead %x when printing a pointer in hex format. 
Like this:

```
//hexadecimal
printf("location of val in hex with ptr is: %#x\n", ptr); 
printf("location of val in hex without a pointer is: %p\n", &val );
```

Comment: Technically, there is a need to cast to `void *` for `%p` as `%p` is for printing `void *`.  There are few machines these days where you'd notice a difference, but I learned C on a machine where, when given `int i = 0; int *ip = &i; char *cp = (char *)&i;`, the values in `ip` and `cp` were not the same when converted to `int` (which was big enough to hold an address).  Your code would not work correctly on a Win64 platform; there, a pointer is an 8-byte quantity but `%lu` expects a 4-byte unsigned integer.

Comment: Yes, for 64bit better use %llu instead. However, pointer is pointer and casting is needed when the value is taken away or size is determined. Other than that, should work.