# Wrong entries with /proc/pid/stat?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, memory-mapping

I have written a simple C program, with some global and static variables. Some code, and output can be shown below.

**Sample source code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int g1, g2;

int main(){

     printf("g1:%p g2:%p\n", &g1, &g2);

     return 0;
}
```

**Output:**

```
g1:0x6061b0 g2:0x6061c0
```

Such variables falls in the data segment. They could be in the initialised subsection, or in the uninitialised (bss) subsection. I print their addresses to check where they are in memory, and then I compare these values with the values of `start_data` and `end_data` entries of the `/proc/<pid>/stat` pseudo-file. My variables **do not** fall in that area.

**Limits that /proc/pid/stat gives me:**

```
start_data: 604e10
end_data:   605180
```

From [documentation](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html)

> **45) start_data**  %lu  (since Linux 3.3)
>                           Address above which program initialized and
>                           uninitialized (BSS) data are placed.
>
> **(46) end_data**  %lu  (since Linux 3.3)
>                           Address below which program initialized and
>                           uninitialized (BSS) data are placed.

I have managed to get the correct area of the `data segment` using a `map file` produced by the `linker`, however by using the `proc` interface it would be much cleaner (easier, faster,..) .

**Correct limits I found using mapfile from linker:**

```
start: 605168
end:   606290
```

I am using Ubuntu Server x64, with Linux 3.13.

**Full output of stat:**

```
29505 (myexec) R 29504 29504 1438 34822 29504 24640 52 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 20 0 1 0 55253161 4308992 24 18446744073709551615 4194304 4210644 140737488347232 140737488337560 140737348896784 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 17 0 0 0 0 0 0 6311440 6312320 6320128 140737488347816 140737488347831 140737488347831 140737488351209 0
```

**Output of map_files:**

```
total 0
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 400000-41a000 -> /bin/ls
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 619000-61a000 -> /bin/ls
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 61a000-61b000 -> /bin/ls
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff649e000-7ffff64a9000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff64a9000-7ffff66a8000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff66a8000-7ffff66a9000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff66a9000-7ffff66aa000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_files-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff66aa000-7ffff66b5000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff66b5000-7ffff68b4000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff68b4000-7ffff68b5000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff68b5000-7ffff68b6000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_nis-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff68b6000-7ffff68cd000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff68cd000-7ffff6acc000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff6acc000-7ffff6acd000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff6acd000-7ffff6ace000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnsl-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff6ad0000-7ffff6ad9000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff6ad9000-7ffff6cd8000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff6cd8000-7ffff6cd9000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff6cd9000-7ffff6cda000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libnss_compat-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff6cda000-7ffff6fa3000 -> /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff6fa3000-7ffff6fa7000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1.1.0
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff6fa7000-7ffff71a6000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1.1.0
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff71a6000-7ffff71a7000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1.1.0
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff71a7000-7ffff71a8000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libattr.so.1.1.0
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff71a8000-7ffff71ab000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff71ab000-7ffff73aa000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff73aa000-7ffff73ab000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff73ab000-7ffff73ac000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff73ac000-7ffff73e9000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff73e9000-7ffff75e8000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff75e8000-7ffff75e9000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff75e9000-7ffff75ea000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre.so.3.13.1
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff75ea000-7ffff77a5000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff77a5000-7ffff79a4000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff79a4000-7ffff79a8000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff79a8000-7ffff79aa000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff79af000-7ffff79b6000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1.1.0
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff79b6000-7ffff7bb5000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1.1.0
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff7bb5000-7ffff7bb6000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1.1.0
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff7bb6000-7ffff7bb7000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libacl.so.1.1.0
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff7bb7000-7ffff7bd7000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff7bd7000-7ffff7dd6000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff7dd6000-7ffff7dd7000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff7dd7000-7ffff7dd8000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff7dda000-7ffff7dfd000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff7ffc000-7ffff7ffd000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
lr-------- 1 root root 64 Apr 21 22:32 7ffff7ffd000-7ffff7ffe000 -> /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.19.so
```

Any thoughts?
Cheers.

Comment: procfs content changes across kernel versions. What version of kernel are you using? Are you sure you are looking at the right fields and you have kernel >=3.3 (which supports start_data and end_data)?

Comment: @BlueMoon yes for both! See updated question!

Comment: It shows correctly (i.e. range matches with maps) for your code on my ubuntu 3.11, i686. Can you post the exact content of `stat` and `ls -l ../map_files` ?

Comment: The addresses as seen inside the program are physical addresses -> virtual addresses by the kernel.  Your program reports the virtual addresses. proc may be showing you what the kernel sees - the actual physical addresses. The end of memory is dynamic --  The brk system call changes the ending memory address of your resident working set size as the program runs.  Try looking at a trace to see what I mean.

Comment: @BlueMoon please see updated question! And keep in mind that addresses are shown in decimal!

Comment: Yes, it's in decimal & converting it matches the map_files range. `ls` as root (sudo), ur output is not useful atm.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seem to be yes (or incorrect documentation).

ELF uses a small trick for specifying BSS (I cut leading zeroes):

```
$ objdump -x ./a.out

LOAD off    0x00000e00 vaddr 0x00600e00 paddr 0x00600e00 align 2**21
     filesz 0x00000258 memsz 0x00000268 flags rw-
```

For that PT_LOAD:

```
vaddr = 0x00600e00
vaddr + filesz = 0x00601058
vaddr + memsz = 0x00601068
```

So bytes [0x00600e00;0x00601058) are loaded into memory from file, while last 0x10 bytes should be present in memory too, but not loaded from ELF file -- they are zeroed because it is BSS. You can check that with objdump too:

```
25 .bss    00000010  00601058  00601058  00001058  2**2
           ^ size    ^ base address
```

However, inside binfmt loader for ELF, only `vaddr + filesz` is counted as `end_data` (see [fs/binfmt_elf.c](http://lxr.linux.no/#linux+v3.13/fs/binfmt_elf.c#L861)):

```
k = elf_ppnt->p_vaddr + elf_ppnt->p_filesz;

if (k > elf_bss)
    elf_bss = k;
if ((elf_ppnt->p_flags & PF_X) && end_code < k)
    end_code = k;
if (end_data < k)
    end_data = k;
k = elf_ppnt->p_vaddr + elf_ppnt->p_memsz;
if (k > elf_brk)
    elf_brk = k;
```

So:

- `end_data` points to last byte loaded from file
- `elf_bss` points to first byte of BSS (not exposed, used internally)
- `elf_brk` points to last byte of BSS (not exposed, used internally)

You can check `/proc/PID/maps` -- it should show more reliable results.

P.S. It seems, that in-kernel documentation have been changed by random stranger: https://lkml.org/lkml/2011/12/6/604

Comment: nice answer. Thanks for taking time to explain it! However, why the `start_data` is wrong too?

As for your last recommendation, I wished /proc/PID/maps was more reliable. Have a look to my yesterdays' question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681712/why-global-variables-are-stored-in-heap/29683894#29683894

Comment: @Paschalis, there is more than _your data_ is falling to a data segment. Check that with objdump, you can find service sections like `.got` and `.jcr`.

Comment: Based on what you suggest it seems the doc is not correct then.

Comment: @myaut I found these sections on a `mapfile` I produced from the `linker`. Don't know what they are though.
I just verified what you said, by introducing an **initialised** variable, and it is at address 605180!

Comment: **This means that:** The area covers only **initialised data**, and **NOT** BSS. **Documentation is wrong.**

Comment: @Paschalis: you may read /proc/self/maps with that code: https://ideone.com/H6oFiQ It work correctly for me.

Comment: @myaut in my case, the BSS segment extends in the heap segment. Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29681712/why-global-variables-are-stored-in-heap/