# Print the addresses of a linked list

Tags: c, data-structures, linked-list

How the variables `*head` and `temp` values outputted.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* Link list node */
struct node {
    int data;
    struct node *next;
};

void pushList(struct node **head, int item)
{
    struct node *temp = (struct node *) malloc(sizeof (struct node));
    temp->data = item;
    temp->next = *head;
    *head = temp;

    printf("*temp = %ld\n"
           "temp->data = %d\n"
           "temp = %ld\n"
           "&temp = %ld\n", *temp, (temp)->data, temp, &temp);
    printf
        ("*head = %ld\n"
         "**head = %ld\n"
         "(*head)->next = %ld\n"
         "head = %ld\n"
         "&head = %ld\n", *head, **head, (*head)->next, head, &head);
}

int main()
{
    struct node *head = NULL;
    printf("&head = %ld\n", &head);
    pushList(&head, 1);
    printf("\n");
    pushList(&head, 2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output of the above is:

```
&head = 2686732
*temp = 1
temp->data = 0
temp = 1
&temp = 10292624
*head = 10292624 
**head = 1
(*head)->next = 0
head = 0
&head = 2686732

*temp = 2
temp->data = 10292624
temp = 2
&temp = 10292656
*head = 10292656
**head = 2
(*head)->next = 10292624 
head = 10292624 
&head = 2686732
```

Why is the value of `*head` equal to `&temp`?

Comment: '(*head)->next,head,&head);' - takes the adddress of a local parameter:(

Comment: Use your debugger to trace execution.

Comment: See [Correct format specifier to print pointer address?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658)  The correct header to use is `<stdlib.h>`; the `<malloc.h>` header _does_ declare `malloc()` et al, but also provides other facilities which you are not using (and which people who use `<malloc.h>` instead of, or as well as, `<stdlib.h>` almost never use).

Comment: Thanks for this helpful knowledge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are passing `*temp` to `printf`, with the format specifier `%ld`, indicating `long int`. However, the type of `*temp` is not `long int` but `struct node`, which differs in size with `long int`. This means that `printf`'s argument parsing logic gets messed up and you can't trust any of the output from that call to `printf`. For example, note how `(temp)->data` is showing as `0` and `10292624` instead of `1` and `2`.

Further, you are using the wrong output specifiers for most fields (though the result might be correct depending on architecture, it is not portable). Try turning up the warnings level on your compiler (for gcc, `-Wall` will give you a bunch of warnings about this). You should optionally cast pointers to `void*` and use the `%p` specifier.

This (specifically, passing `struct node`s to `printf`) is what makes `*head` and `&temp` come up as equal. Try changing your `printf`s to the following and they should make more sense:

```
printf("\n%d\t%p\t%p\n",(temp)->data,temp,&temp);
printf("\n%p\t%p\t%p\t\n\n%p\n\n\n",*head,
(*head)->next,head,&head);
```

Note that I removed the arguments `*temp` and `**head` since they refer to actual `struct node`s, which `printf` can't handle.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, The line `*head = temp` makes `*head` being always the same as `temp`.

Function `pushList()` always adds new element at the beginning of linked list, and `head` points to the first element of linked list all the time. So, it is obviously `*head` equals `temp` for the reason that `temp` points to the last allocated element which will be inserted at the beginning.

BTW, there is a better way to print the address of a variable that to use `%p` instead of `%ld` which will make your program more portable.