# Compiler gives warning when printing the address of a variable

Tags: c, gcc, printf, clang, format-specifiers

I made a very simple program to print the address of two variables.

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int a,b;
    printf("%u\n%u",&a,&b);
    return 0;
}
```

But, the Clang-3.7 compiler gives warning as:

> warning: format specifies type 'unsigned int' but the argument has type 'int *' [-Wformat]`

But, when I compiled with GCC-5.x, it gave no warnings. Which of them is correct?

One thing I know is that doing `unsigned int num=&a;` would be wrong as address can only be stored in a pointer. But, is it correct for the compiler to give warning when printing the address?

I compiled my program from [gcc.godbolt.org](http://gcc.godbolt.org/)

Comment: GCC, if configured correctly (`-Wall`) gives: `warning: format '%u' expects argument of type 'unsigned int', but argument 2 has type 'int *' [-Wformat=]`

Comment: I think this question (& the posted answers) is a good candidate for canonical duplicate though :) Will add it to favourites.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Correct format specifier to print pointer (address)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-address)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

`%p` is the correct format specifier to print addresses:

```
printf("%p\n%p",(void*)&a, (void*)&b);
```

The C standard requires that the argument corresponding to `%p` should be of type `void*`. So the casts are there.

C11, [Reference](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p8):

> p    The argument shall be a pointer to void. The value of the pointer
>   is converted to a sequence of printing characters, in an
>   implementation-defined manner.

Using incorrect format specifier is [*undefined behavior*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior). A compiler is not *required* to produce any diagnostics for undefined behaviors. So both are gcc and clang are correct.

GCC 5.1 does produce warnings on my system without any additional 
options. And GCC [godbolt produces warnings](http://goo.gl/zH1K32) with stricter compiler options: `-Wall -Wextra`. In general, you should compile with strictest compiler options.

Comment: IMHO, `-Wextra` is not required for _this_ case. `-Wall` should suffice. Just saying :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh Just `-Wformat` is enough to find this *particular* issue. But in general, it's a good idea to compile with both.

Comment: Completely agree. Just wanted to point out the _exact_ option, nothing else. Cheers.

Answer (score 4):

The correct format specifier for printing an address (pointer) is `%p` and you need to cast the argument to `void *`.

**Hence, the warning is valid and should be there.**

> *But, when I compiled with GCC-5.x, it gave no warnings*

In case of `gcc`, please include `-Wall`<sup>Note</sup> compiler option  and try to compile. I believe it will throw the (same) warning we're expecting.

---

Note: Actually, `-Wformat`, which checks for the type of supplied argument to `printf()` and `scanf()` family calls. `-Wall` enables `-Wformat`.

Comment: Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You got this error because format-specifier `%u` accepts `unsigned-integer`, whereas what you are supplying in your code is a pointer to a memory location.

You can print address of memory location held by pointer by specifying type of the argument as `(void*)`, this will generate no errors and print the address of memory location in decimal format.

```
printf("%u\n%u",(void*)&a,(void*)&b);
```

Also, this is not the correct way to print a pointer, the correct way is to use specifier `%p`, which will print the address of the memory location in hexadecimal format.

```
printf("%p\n%p",(void*)&a,(void*)&b);
```

Hope that helps.