# Explanation regarding character pointer for string

Tags: c, arrays, string, pointers, character

Hi I'm new to programming.
In the following code `str` is a pointer to a character, so `str` should contain the address of the character 'h'. Therefore %p should be used to print that address.  But I don't understand how %s is used for printing a pointer parameter.

```
    #include<stdio.h>

    int main (){
    char s[] = "hello";
    char *str = s;
    int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *b = a;
    printf("%s\n", str);        // I don't understand how this works ? 
    printf("%c\n", *str);       // This statement makes sense
    printf("%c\n", *(str + 1)); // This statement also makes sense.
    printf("%p\n",str);         // This prints the address of the pointer str. This too makes sense.
    printf("%d\n",*b);          // makes sense, is the same as the second print.
    //      printf("%d",b);     // I don't understand why str pointer works but this gives a compile error
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What's not clear? Why a string format specifier works with a string? Because it is defined to work...

Comment: I am not able to understand the first print. I think if the first print works the last print in the comment should also work but thats not true so thats my question, thanks.

Comment: Why shouldn't `printf("%d", b);` give error?

Comment: @user6353278 What exactly you don't understand? How come `str` being an array `hello` is printed?

Comment: yes why is that error happening and whydoes the first print work.

Comment: Why do you think it *shouldn't* work?

Comment: The error is due to the format specifier is not matching the actual parameter type.

Comment: I understand str is a pointer to the array s, so it points to the first character which is h. Thats why *str prints h and *(str+1) prints e.

Comment: Thanks eugene agreed but can you explain the first print ?

Comment: I searched resource I had I studied the pointer chapter on the deitel book I searched on other programming websites but i couldnt figure it out. So I asked it here.

Comment: The thing that i can't understand is that str being a pointer should contain an address but when i print str with %s it prints hello.

Comment: `%s` means: retrieve a `char*` argument. Dereference the pointer and print the character, and subsequent characters until a `\0` is encountered.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-address

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char s[] = "hello";
```

Declares an array of zero-terminated characters called s. Its the same as writing

```
char s[6] = { 'h', 'e', 'l', 'l', 'o', '\0' };
```

As you can see, the quotation marks are a shorthand.

---

```
char *str = s;
```

This declares `str` to be a pointer to a character. It then makes `str` point to the first character in `s`. In other words, `str` contains the address of the first character in `s`.

---

```
int a[] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
```

Declares an array of integers. It initializes them to the values 1-5, inclusive.

---

```
int *b = a;
```

Declares `b` to be a pointer to an int. It then makes `b` point to the first int in `a`.

---

```
printf("%s\n", str);
```

The `%s` specifier accepts the address of the first character in the string. `printf` then walks from that address, printing the characters it sees, until it sees the `\0` character at the end.

---

```
printf("%c\n", *str);
```

This prints the first character in `str`. Since `str` is pointing to a character (the first character in the string), then `*str` should obtain the character being pointed at (the first character in the string).

---

```
printf("%c\n", *(str + 1));
```

This prints the second character in `str`. This is the long way of writing `str[1]`. The logic behind this is pointer arithmetic. If `str` is the address of a character, then `str + 1` is the address of the next character in the array. Since `(str + 1)` is an address, it may be dereferenced. Thus, the `*` obtains the character 1 character past the first character of the array.

---

```
printf("%p\n",str);
```

The `%p` specifier expects a pointer, just like `%s` would, but it does something else. Instead of printing the contents of a string, it simply prints the address the pointer is containing, in hex.

---

```
printf("%d\n",*b);
```

This prints the first `int` in the array pointed to by `b`. This is equivalent to writing `b[0]`.

---

```
printf("%d",b);
```

`b` is an `int *`, not an `int`, which is what `%d` expects. If you were trying to print the address of the first element of the array, the specifier would be `%p`, not `%d`. Also, this line should not generate a compiler error. Instead, it should have been a runtime undefined behavior, since the compiler does not know what a `printf` format string is.

Comment: `printf("%c\n", *str);` prints the first character. `*str` is the simplified result of `*(str + 0));` (where obviously `+ 0` does nothing). `