# Why am i getting weird output from my pointer?

Tags: c, string, pointers

So i am going to do some string manipulation, but when i try to print out what my pointer is pointing to at time time, i get really weird output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (){

    size_t n = 10;
    char *mystring = malloc(10);
    int line = 0;
    int tokens = 0;
    char *ptr;

    if(mystring==NULL){
            fprintf(stderr, "No memory\n");
            exit(1);
    }

    while(getline(&mystring, &n, stdin)>0){
             printf("len = %lu, mystring = %s\n", strlen(mystring), mystring);
             printf("let's tokenize this string\n line = %d tokens = %d\n", line, tokens);

            ptr = mystring;

            printf("ptr = %ch\n", ptr[0]);
    }

return 0;
}
```

This is what my output looks like when i enter hello

len = 6, mystring = hello

let's tokenize this string
 line = 0 tokens = 0

ptr = hh

what's with the double hh?

Comment: I believe you are looking for `%c`. The first H is from the first character in `hello` while the second is from the `h` in your `printf`.

Comment: i see, i feel like an idiot lol.  Thank you for pointing that out to me

Comment: Happens to the best of us no worries!

Comment: it would be a good idea for you to NOT malloc() but rather: `char *mystring = NULL; size_t n = 0;`  and call free() and reset the values at the end of each pass through the while loop,

Comment: because the function: `getline()` can read right past a NUL char, the code should use the `n` variable for the length, not the results of a call to `strlen()`

Comment: the posted code never sets the variables `line` and `tokens` after their initial initialization to 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is what you're printing. You are printing `ptr = <ptr[0]>h`. There is an extra `h` after `%c` in your `printf()` statement. You probably want to use:

```
        printf("ptr = %c\n", ptr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

The format specifier for printing a character is `%c`.  You have `%ch`, which is saying "print the character given by the next parameter, then print an 'h'".

Get rid of the extra `h` in your format string:

```
printf("ptr = %c\n", ptr[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

> > ```
> > printf("ptr = %ch\n", ptr[0]);
> > ```
>
> ptr = hh
>
> what's with the double hh?

The **first** `h` comes from the first character of the `hello` string, corresponds to `ptr[0]`, and is there since you used `%c` in the `printf` format string.

The **second** `h` is there since you put it there in the `printf` format string, after `%c`.

The correct printf call would be something like:

```
printf("ptr = %c\n", ptr[0]);
```

If you want to print an *address* (pointer), you may want to consider [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9053658/1629821) (you can use the `%p` format specifier).