# Convert string formatted memory address to pointer in C

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, char

I have a text file with the memory addresses of certain components of a program. For instance part of that text file looks like this:

```
00400000-0040b000
```

or

```
7f9ae612f000-7f9ae62ee000
```

I have already read the file into my program and assigned a char[] with the first address (00400000).

I also have a structure with a null pointer

```
struct myStruct
{
    void *address;
}
```

And I would like the pointer `*address` to have the value of `0x00400000`, how would I do this?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: It's (apparently) simpler than you think: `address = (void *) 0x00400000`

Comment: I think he wants to read that memory address from a file.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude He wants to read it `string-formatted`. You can't just cast that to `void *`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sscanf()` to parse the string as a hex integer and then typecast the resulting integer to a `void*` pointer.  For example:

```
char str[] = "00400000";
unsigned long ul;
struct myStruct s;

sscanf(str, "%lx", &ul);
s.address = (void*) (uintptr_t) ul;
```

Comment: Wouldnt %p do this directly?

Comment: I now get an error listed below

 "cast to pointer from integer of different size [-Wint-to-pointer-cast] memReg.startAddr = (void*) i;"

Comment: @BionicSheep: Your addresses look like 32-bit values, but your compiler seems to be complaining about different sizes.  What size are your `unsigned int` and `void *`?

Comment: use %lu and uintptr_t

Comment: @MarkYisri that works with the errors but for any addresses with letters in them it fails

Comment: sorry, %lx @bionicsheep

Comment: @Vality although `%p` is indeed meant for pointers, its format is platform/implementation specific, so it is not suitable for the OP's example.

Comment: ill post as an answer later.

Comment: `"%lx"` is not the specified matching specifier for `uintptr_t`.

Answer (score 0):

If the *same* instance of the program printed `"00400000-0040b000"` then reading a `void*` back via `scanf("%p"...` is possible. Else the result is undefined.

`p` specifier:

> Matches an implementation-deﬁned set of sequences, which should be the same as the set of sequences that may be produced by the %p conversion of the `fprintf` function. The corresponding argument shall be a pointer to a pointer to void. The input item is converted to a pointer value in an implementation-deﬁned manner. If the input item is a value converted earlier during the same program execution, the pointer that results shall compare equal to that value; otherwise the behavior of the %p conversion is **undeﬁned**.  C11dr §7.21.6.2  12

```
struct myStruct x;
if (fscanf(stream, "%p", &x.address) == 1) Success();
```

Answer (score 0):

**[Source:](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/beginner/144379/#msg761180)**

> First of all %x writes `unsigned int`. There is no guarantee that pointer size = `unsigned int` size.
>
> As there is no format specifier which takes `uintptr_t`, you need to manualy check your pointer size in program and then select correct format specifier.

Therefore, to comply with the standard, you have to manually use the `sizeof` operator on `void *` and `unsigned int` and compare them. If they are equal, you can use `%x` as the format.

Otherwise, you need to take appropriate action, and use a different format.

Of course, if this is just a test project, it won't matter to do a dynamic check at runtime. Just hardcode it to the correct value. Be sure to leave a `FIXME` though, so you can come back and add dynamic checking later.

**Additionally,**

We discussed in the comments about the format specifiers, and you specified that `%lx` had correct results. Since it is guarenteed that `%lx` can print a value of at least `uint32_t`, your `void *` must be at least the size of `uint32_t`.

**Additionally number 2,**

**[Source.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053835/6754053)**

If you aren't happy with the implementation-defined behaviour of %p, then use **C99** `<inttypes.h>` and `uintptr_t` instead:

```
printf("0x%" PRIXPTR "\n", (uintptr_t)your_pointer);
```

**Please note that the above solution requires *C99* to work properly.**