# No error at all, why?

Tags: c, printf, format-specifiers

I'm testing this code ,but why no error at all?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int a = 1025;
    int *p;
    p = &a;

    // now I declare a char variable , 
    char *p0;
    p0 = (char*) p; // type casting
    printf("", sizeof(char));

    // is %d correct here ?????
    printf("Address = %d, value = %d\n", p0, *p0);

}
```

My question :
Is `%d` correct here? since `%d` is integer not for character, why no error at all?

Comment: Actually the problem is the first `%d` where you are passing an address: you should use `%p`. `printf("Address = %p, value = %d\n", (void *)p0, *p0);` For the second one `char` value is just promoted to `int`.

Comment: Moreover errors/warnings depends also on how you are compiling your code: using `gcc -Wall -Wextra  -pedantic-errors test.c -o test -std=c11  -g`, you have  `warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘char *’ [-Wformat=]
  printf("Address = %d, value = %d\n", p0, *p0);`

Comment: [Correct format specifier to print pointer (address)?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9053658/995714)

Answer (score 4):

In your case

```
 p0 = (char*) p;
```

is valid, because `char *` can be used to access any other types. Related, quoting `C11`, chapter §6.3.2.3

> [...] When a pointer to an object is converted to a pointer to a character type,
>   the result points to the lowest addressed byte of the object. Successive increments of the
>   result, up to the size of the object, yield pointers to the remaining bytes of the object.

However, in case of

```
    printf("Address = %d, value = %d\n", p0, *p0);
```

causes [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), as you're passing a pointer (`p0`) to `%d` (Look at the first "pair" of conversion specifier and corresponding argument). You should use `%p` and cast the argument to `void *`, something like

```
   printf("Address = %p, value = %d\n", (void *)p0, *p0);
```

Then, to answer

> *No error at all, why?*

because the issue is not with the syntax or any constraint violation which the compiler is supposed to complain about. It's purely mis-use of *given power*. :)

Comment: Note, some compilers warn for format specifier mismatches. E.g. recent versions of gcc and clang with `-Wall`

Comment: @M.M.: Many nonrecent versions did, too. It was certainly present in 2.95 (c. 1999), and i think it was already old.

Answer (score 1):

It's undefined behaviour because `p0` is a `char*`, the code `printf("Address = %d, value = %d\n", p0, *p0)` and `%d` is not a valid conversion specifier for character pointers.

Comment: `constraint violation`...can you please elaborate?

Comment: Thanks, just downvoted, as you're absolutely wrong. :)

Comment: @SouravGhosh hello sir, I have changed my answer.

Comment: `%d is not a valid conversion specifier for character pointers` it is not for _any_ pointer, as a matter of fact.