# C: print an array

Tags: c

I've started learning C yesterday, and the only other language I know is Python.

I'm having some trouble with arrays, because they are quite different from the Python lists.

I tried to print an array, not an element of it, but the array itself.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int array[3] = {1, 2, 3}

main(){
    printf("%i, %i", array[0], array);
}
```

What I got is *1* (obviously), and *4210692*, which I can't understand from where it comes.

What I wanted to do first, is to make an array of arrays:

```
float a[1][4];
float b[4];

a[0] = b;
main(){
    printf("%f", a[0]);
}
```

but it returns a strange number, and not something like *this is an array* as Python does.

Comment: I'd recommend to get a good textbook about C and get the basics right. First is to forget about Python when coding in C.

Comment: As an aside, it should be `int main()`, not just `main()`

Comment: printf won't print complex objects, only numbers and strings. For anything else you have to write a function that does all the steps for you (to get to the numbers and strings). If you want built-in behavior more close to python then maybe you should try C++ instead.

Comment: The large number is a mangled form of the address where the array is stored.  Arrays are second-class citizens in C.  They exist, but they're very closely related to pointers.  You can't do many operations on whole arrays in C without writing loops (about the only thing you can do is initialize a whole array, if you're careful).  And you can't do assignments like `a[0] = b;` outside of functions in C.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "*wierd*" value you get from printing `array` is actually the memory address of the first element of the array.

In order to print an array, you need to use a for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < array_size; i++)
    printf("%d\n", array[i]);
```

Comment: I'd rather do like `printf("%d%c", array[i], (i  < array_size - 1) ? '\t' : '\n')`

Answer (score 3):

That is the memory address of the array (because of [array-to-pointer decaying](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1461432/3425536)).

To correctly print pointers though, you should use [`%p`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9053658/3425536).

Comment: To be more precise, identical for `printf`.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use for loop, like this :

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int arr[10] = {12, 32, 34, 13, 42, 35, 14, 43, 16, 43}
    for(int i = 0; a <= 10; a++)
    {
        printf("%i ", arr[i]);
    }
}
```

output :

```
12 32 34 13 42 35 14 43 16 43
```

or you can make a Python-like array printer by making a function

```
void printarr(int *arr, int size){
    for (int i = 0; i <= size; i++)
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            printf("[%i, ", arr[i]);
        } else if (i == size)
        {
            printf("%i]", arr[i]);
        } else
        {
            printf("%i, ", arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

with that, you can print

```
[12, 32, 34, 13, 42, 35, 14, 43, 16, 43]
```