# Unable to extract bytes from integer correctly

Tags: c

prog i wrote works for some values of integer but not for all... why ??

program output

```
int value is abcdef78
first byte is 78 addr is 2686741
second byte is ffffffef addr is 2686742
third byte is ffffffcd addr is 2686743
fourth byte is ffffffab addr is 2686744
```

expected output

```
int value is abcdef78
first byte is 78 addr is 2686741
second byte is ef addr is 2686742
third byte is cd addr is 2686743
fourth byte is ab addr is 2686744

Process returned 0 (0x0)   execution time : 0.015 s
Press any key to continue.
```

Code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{

    int i=0xabcdef78;
    int *ip;

    printf("int value is %x\n",i);   //  *ip contents of address

    char c;
    char *cp;
    cp=&i;
    c = *cp;
    printf("first byte is %x addr is %d\n",*cp++,cp);
    printf("second byte is %x addr is %d\n",*cp++,cp);
    printf("third byte is %x addr is %d\n",*cp++,cp);
    printf("fourth byte is %x addr is %d\n",*cp++,cp);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Change `%x` → `%hhx` and `%d`  → `%p`. Also, you should increment `cp` after the printf statements if you want the program to work reliably.

Comment: This code invokes *undefined behavior*. You have unsequenced modification and access to `cp` in each of your output calls.

Comment: Perhaps try to use unit_8t data types instead of int.

Comment: [use `%p` to print pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9053658/995714)

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that your char is getting promoted to int with sign extension. 0xef in binary form is:

```
1110 1111
```

and it get promoted to an 32 bit integer with a sign extension like this:

```
1111 1111  1111 1111  1111 1111  1110 1111
```

While 0x78 in binary form is:

```
0111 1000
```

The most significant bit is 0 so it get promoted like this:

```
0000 0000  0000 0000  0000 0000  0111 1000
```

There are two solutions:

1. Do not print your char as a 32 bit value, i.e. use %hhx instead of %x.
2. Make your char unsigned, i.e. unsigned char *cp instead of char *cp

Answer (score 0):

You should modify your code like

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int i = 0xabcdef78;

    printf("int value is %x\n", i);   //  *ip contents of address

    unsigned char *cp;
    cp = (unsigned char *)(&i);

    printf("1st byte is 0x%02X addr is %p\n", cp[0], (void *)(&cp[0]) );
    printf("2nd byte is 0x%02X addr is %p\n", cp[1], (void *)(&cp[1]) );
    printf("3rd byte is 0x%02X addr is %p\n", cp[2], (void *)(&cp[2]) );
    printf("4th byte is 0x%02X addr is %p\n", cp[3], (void *)(&cp[3]) );

    return 0;
}
```

As you can see:

1. I changed the format specifier for address: must be `%p` and passed arg must be `void *`
2. I removed the pointer increment because it is UB. Take a look at [this famous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/949433/why-are-these-constructs-using-undefined-behavior). If you want to inc your pointer, you must inc it after `printf`.
3. You must use `unsigned char` to point bytes of your integer, otherwise, asu you are facing, values greater then `7F` will be considered as negative.

OUTPUT

```
int value is abcdef78
1st byte is 0x78 addr is 0x7ffdda43fc8c
2nd byte is 0xEF addr is 0x7ffdda43fc8d
3rd byte is 0xCD addr is 0x7ffdda43fc8e
4th byte is 0xAB addr is 0x7ffdda43fc8f
```

Answer (score -1):

Delete the statement

```
    int *ip;
```

as you never use it (not important). Then:

Instead of

```
printf("first byte is %x addr is %d\n",*cp++,cp);
printf("second byte is %x addr is %d\n",*cp++,cp);
printf("third byte is %x addr is %d\n",*cp++,cp);
printf("fourth byte is %x addr is %d\n",*cp++,cp);
```

use

```
printf("first byte  is %hhx, addr is %ld\n", *cp++, cp);
printf("second byte is %hhx, addr is %ld\n", *cp++, cp);
printf("third byte  is %hhx, addr is %ld\n", *cp++, cp);
printf("fourth byte is %hhx, addr is %ld\n", *cp++, cp);
```

as the logic of your program is correct, but the output is *bad formatted*.

Comment: This doesn't fix the undefined behaviour issue.

Comment: @squeamis - You are perfectly right, thanks. I wanted correct my answer but meanwhile [LPs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3436922/lps) put a correct one.