# Which suffixes and format-signs(scanf,printf) for all different datatypes in C are correct?

Tags: c, types, printf, scanf, suffix

I'm very confused by all these **suffixes** and different **format-signs** for all datatypes of **C** and I can't find any website that tells me **all of them**. Additionally every website **tells something different :(**. So I created this table including all suffixes and all format-signs for these datatypes but I'm very unsure if it's really correct. Could you **please** check the table?

[image]

Comment: Have a look at http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/    It is claimed to be correct for both C and C++ as of the 2011 standards.

Comment: [The related C Standard's chapter](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1).

Comment: There are often extensions added by compilers and new ones have developed over the years with new standards - there is a lot of out of date stuff on the web.  Find which standard you are writing to and then look at that standard and stick with those, there are obvious disadvantages with using extensions.

Comment: By the way, you might also consider pointers, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-address

Comment: To add to the fun... not all compilers support all extensions. On windows, MinGW doesn't support the `h` modifiers, but `cl.exe` does. (no I don't know why, just that both MinGW and MinGW-TDM exhibit that behavior)

Comment: a `char` type can be `signed` or `unsigned`, this depends on the implementation of the compiler (it is not specified in the C standard)

Comment: depending on the underlying hardware, the actual size of each of the types can vary.  TO get fixed sizing, include the header file `stdint.h`  and use the type names listed in that header file.  The name will look like `int32_t` and `uint32_t`  (there are lots more defined)

Comment: in the posted tables for integers and floats, they can all be both `signed` and `unsigned` so the columns regarding that condition are rather meaningless

Comment: I think floats doesnt support to be unsigned.