# Why does %d,and %p give different values?

Tags: c

As you can see in the program, The first output is 6356744 and the second output is 0060FF08, why is it different? Is the `%d` typecasting it into an integer, if so, how?

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main()

{

    int *a;
    int b = 7;
    a = &b;
    printf(" The value of a = %d",a);
    printf("\n The value of a= %p",a);

}
```

Comment: UB͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏͏

Comment: 6356744 is 0060FF08 in decimals.

Comment: I don't understand why so many answer, we don't have already answer this a millions time ?

Comment: @Stargateur We might need a canonical duplicate for them. I don't know of a post that's good enough to be added to the FAQ.

Comment: @Lundin is this enough https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053835/7076153 ?

Comment: @Stargateur Oh that one is pretty good! I'll add that one to the C tag wiki.

Comment: Done. For those who's not aware, we have a pretty detailed FAQ list of canonical duplicates in the [C tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c/info).

Answer (score 1):

Printing a pointer with `%d` is formally undefined behavior, meaning anything can happen, including a program crash. Your program will for example likely break when you compile it as a 64 bit application, where `int` is 32 bits but a pointer is likely 64 bits. Therefore, always use `%p` and never anything else when printing a pointer.

There is no implicit conversion taking place - the printf family of functions doesn't have that kind of intelligence - it doesn't know the type passed. With the format specifier, *you* tell the function which type it is getting. And if you lie to printf and say "I'll give you an int" and then give it a pointer, you unleash bugs. This makes the printf family of functions very dangerous in general.

(The only implicit conversion that take place in printf is when you pass small integer types or float, in which case the "default argument promotions" take place and promote the parameter either to `int` or `double`. This is not the case here, however.)

In this specific case, you happened to get the decimal representation of `0x0060FF08`, which is by no means guaranteed.

Pedantically, you should also cast the pointer to type `(void*)` since this is what `%p` expects.

Comment: "_The only implicit conversion that take place in printf ..._" That formally is not a conversion by printf but by C in general (argument promotion).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie The default argument promotions are invoked for all variable argument list functions, printf being no exception. C11 6.5.2.2/7.

Comment: So it is not an implicit conversion of _printf_, which is my point.

Comment: Further to your comment reply, does the promotions only take place for variable argument lists? I thought they are for arguments of all functions.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie You still get them if you do something smelly, such as not using proper function prototype format.

Comment: Hmmm...C11 6.5.2.2.6 and 7 are a bit hard to read. Seems there is no promotion when there is a complete prototype (but how to pass small int if not promoted to full int on e.g. x86, or how to pass a single char? Maybe that is not called "promotion" but part of the ABI)

Comment: @PaulOgilvie §7 is regarding a properly prototyped variadic function, the relevant part being "The ellipsis notation in a function prototype declarator causes argument type conversion to stop after the last declared parameter. The default argument promotions are performed on trailing arguments." Meaning that if you have `void foo (char x, ...)`, then `x` is not default argument promoted, but the rest of the arguments are.

Comment: and how e.g. `char` is passed is platform/compiler dependent. On x86 it will be placed in an object that can be pushed onto the stack, this object probably being wider than the char, but that is not promotion but ABI. Think I get it; thx.

Answer (score 0):

%p prints a pointer and it's not necessarily hexadecimal, or even a number

Answer (score 0):

If format specifiers do not match the datatype of the provided parameter, you yield undefined behaviour. `%d` expects an integral value, such that when you pass a pointer value, you get undefined behaviour (cf., for example, [cppreference.com-printf](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf)):

> ...If any argument after default argument promotions is not the type
>   expected by the corresponding conversion specifier, or if there are
>   fewer arguments than required by format, the behavior is undefined.

The (only) correct format specifier for printing pointer values is `%p`, usually printing the address in hex format.

One of the undefined behaviours is that `%d` takes the pointer value as an 32/64 bit integral value and hence prints decimals, which - if you printed it using the correct `%p`-format - corresponds to the hex-value of the address (yet in decimal format).

Answer (score 0):

`%d` prints an `int`, in decimal.

`%p` prints a pointer (strictly speaking, a `void *` pointer) in an implementation-defined way, typically in hexadecimal.

On a machine where `int`s and pointers have different sizes, trying to print a pointer using `%d` will typically give a meaningless result.  For example, on a lot of machines these days, `int`s are 32 bits while pointers are 64 bits.  So if you try to print a pointer using `%d`, what you might get is *half* the pointer value, in decimal.

(Strictly speaking, trying to print a pointer using `%d` is undefined, no matter what the relative sizes are.)

Bottom line, use the right printf specifier for the job.  Use `%d` to print ints.  Use `%p` to print pointers.  Don't try to mix 'n' match.