# struct pointer and memory location

Tags: c, struct

```
struct Data
{
    int num;
    struct *next, *prev;
};

typedef struct Data sData;

int main()
{
    sData *head;
    head = NULL;
    printf("%lld %lld", head, &head);
    return 0;
}
```

I am trying to understand deeper about struct pointers and their memory allocations. Why do the printed values differ?

Comment: `head` gives you the value of the un-initialized pointer, what is undefined behavior. `&head` gives you the address of your variable `head`. Why should value and address be the same?

Comment: also, its better to use `%p` to print pointers, check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-address

Comment: _Why is the printed value differ ?_ because `head` and `&head` are not same. when you print `head` it print what it contains which is `NULL` and when you print address of `head` it prints address .

Comment: sorry I forgot to Initialized it as NULL

Comment: `printf("%lld %lld", head, &head);` is not a well defined way to print 2 pointers.  Suggest `printf("%p %p\n", (void*) head, (void*) &head);` instead and report you findings.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code, `head` is a variable. The fact that it is a pointer on `SData` structure is not useful to understand:

- **head** returns the value of the variable `head`, here it is NULL.
- **&head** returns the address of the variable `head`, here it depends on your compiler and linker configuration. As `head` is a local variable, it may be an address of a location in the stack.

Answer (score 1):

Printing "head" you can see the address of memory block where it's pointing (NULL), and printing "&head" you see the adress of memory block where the "head" variable is stored.