# What is the size of the following declaration?

Tags: c, memory

My friend and I are arguing over this one.

```
char **array[2][2];
```

Is the size that this takes up in memory `8 + 2*2*8` — 8 for the pointer to the array of pointers and then 32 for the array of pointers?
Or is it just 8 because we are declaring a pointer to an array of pointers. This declarations doesn't have to allocate space for the array of pointers, just the pointer?

Comment: You have an array of 4 pointers;  it occupies `4 * sizeof(char **)`, which will be 16 or 32 bytes depending on whether it is a 32-but or 64-bit compilation.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Why are u grouping the double pointers together? Why is it not a pointer to an array of pointers?

Comment: Because it is a 2D array of `char **`, @bananateam.  Each element of the array is a `char **`.  There is no extra storage required.

Comment: A pointer to an array of pointers would be written as `char *(*ptr_to_array_of_ptrs)[2];` if the target is a 1D array of pointers.

Comment: You could ask the compiler: `printf("%zu", sizeof(array))`. The compiler is never wrong ;)

Comment: @user3386109 unless they are using a MS compiler that does not support `%zu` :D

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you I didn't know there was a difference!

Comment: @M.M I tried using sizeof on Xcode but it was giving me large negative numbers when I used "%d" and "%lu" as recommended by Xcode.

Comment: See [Correct format specifier to print pointer address?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053835/15168)

Comment: @PeteBecker It seems like youre saying it’s just a pointer, and it can point to anything, so it should be just 8 bytes but apparently this is an array of char**, and is 32 bytes because theres 4.

Comment: @bananateam, the right operators have precedence over the left ones, so it's a two dimensional array with two positions in either direction.  The double pointer has nothing special over the single pointer, as they are represented by an address (well, one is an address of an address, while the other is an address to a char) so there are `2x2 = 4` pointers in the array.  @jonathanLeffler is right in his calculations, and no grouping is done.

Comment: @M.M, in case your compiler doesn't use `%zu` format (that's not a compiler problem, but rather a `printf()` implementation, so it's not VC specific. But then, you can use `%llu` and convert the pointer with a cast, as in `(unsigned long long) sizeof(array)` before passing it to printf.  (same for `%lu` and `(unsigned long) sizeof(array)` if your platform doesn't support 64bit addresses)

Comment: You are asking a question related to `printf(3)` format implementation, which is not a C++ function and tag the question as **C++**.   Remove the C++ tag as this question has nothing to do with the implementation of the `printf(3)` function, so it is not a C++ question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler allocates your whole array (32 bytes). You can investigate these questions with sizeof():

```
#include <stdio.h>
char ** array[2][2];
int main() {
    printf("size = %zu\n", sizeof(array));
    printf("size[0] = %zu\n", sizeof(array[0]));
    printf("size[0][0] = %zu\n", sizeof(array[0][0]));
    return 0;
}
```

On x86_64 architecture returns:

```
size = 32
size[0] = 16
size[0][0] = 8
```

Each pointer is 8 bytes long, and your two-dimensional array contains 4 total.

Comment: hmm i  think i did sizeof the same and used %d but got a huge negative number, dont know what i did

Comment: @bananateam: Using `%d` to print either pointers or `size_t` values (the result of `sizeof()`) is basically wrong.  Use `%p` for pointers (converting to `void *`) and use `%zu` for `size_t`.

Answer (score 9):

As [cdecl](https://cdecl.org/) could have told you (with a little fiddling), your declaration

> ```
> char ** array[2][2];
> ```

declares `array` as an array of two arrays of two pointers to pointers to `char`.  That means a total of four elements of type `char **` (and nothing else).  C does not specify how large pointers are, nor even that pointers to different types have the same size, but it is common on 64-bit implementations for all pointers to be 8 bytes wide.  On such an implementation, the size of the declared object is 2 * 2 * 8 == 32 bytes.  There is no extra pointer.

If you wanted a pointer to a 2 x 2 array of `char *`, that would be different:

```
char * (*array)[2][2];
```

... and the size of that is indeed the size of one pointer.  No storage is reserved in that case for the pointed-to 2D array.

Comment: Okay this makes more sense. I thought it was creating the 2nd case you mention and didnt know there was a distinguishment like that between the 2. THANKS!