# (arr + 2) is equivalent to *(arr + 2) . How?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I am studying how to display elements of 2D array with the help of pointers. Here is the code I tried:

```
#include<stdio.h>  

int main(){

    int arr[3][2] = {  

    {7, 8},
    {6,3},
    {3,4}
    };

    printf("%u\n", (arr + 2));
    printf("%u\n", *(arr + 2)); 
}
```

Output:

```
6487616
6487616
```

I am expecting output of `*(arr + 2)` to be `3`. How is it the same as `(arr + 2)`?

Comment: You need to dereference it twice, since it's a 2D array: `*(*(arr+2))`

Comment: @GovindParmar Would you please explain why?

Comment: `arr[2]` and `*(arr + 2)` are the same by definition in the language (C11 [§6.5.2.1 Array subscripting ¶2](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.2.1p2)).  And you get odd results because you're printing an address, not the value of a cell in the array.  That's officially undefined behaviour; you pass an address to `printf()` but tell it that it's got an unsigned integer to work on.  You might be OK on a 32-bit platform, sort of, more or less.  Results are not remotely reliable on a 64-bit platform.

Comment: The double dereference is necessary because it is a 2D array.  `arr[2]` is a pointer to an array of 2 `int`; `arr[2][0]` and `arr[2][1]` are the two values.  `*arr[2]` would reference the `3` too.

Comment: technically you're getting UB since `%u` is not for printing pointers. [You have to use `%zu`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9053658/995714)

Comment: @phuclv: You're right that `%u` is UB, but so is using `%zu` (that's for printing `size_t`).  You should either use `%p` and cast the pointer to a `void *`, or use `<inttypes.h>` and `PRIuPTR` (or `PRIXPTR` for upper-case hex) plus a cast to `uintptr_t`.

Comment: `printf`-ing pointer values with `%u` triggers undefined behavior. End of story. Your preceived "equivalence" is nothing more than an illusion created by an invalid format specifier in `printf`.

Comment: @phuclv: How is `%zu` better than `%u`??? `%zu` is intended for `size_t` arguments. Pointers are not `size_t`.

Comment: @AnT yes that's a typo. The linked question already said that it should be `%p`

Comment: @phuclv : False. `%zu` requires a `size_t` argument. Any incompatible type will trigger undefined behavior. Pointer arguments will trigger undefined behavior.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

A 2D array is really an array of arrays.

The expression `arr + 2` has type `int (*)[2]`, while `*(arr + 2)` has type `int [2]`.  When printing the former, you have a pointer so that value of the pointer is printed.  In the latter case, you have an array which decays to a pointer to the first element.  So `*(arr + 2)` decays into `arr + 2`, which is the same as the first expression.

Going into more detail on `arr + 2`, `arr` has type `int [3][2]`.  When you add an integer value to it, it decays to a pointer to the first member, so `arr` decays to type `int (*)[2]`, and `arr + 2` also has that type, and points to the subarray containing `{ 3, 4 }`.

Also note that pointers should be printed with the `%p` format specifier, and that the pointer must be casted to `void *`, otherwise you invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).  In this case you were "lucky" that they happened to print the same thing.

To get the output of 3 you were expecting, you need to dereference one more time:

```
*(*(arr + 2))
```

Comment: `*(*(arr + 2));` throws `[Error] expected ')' before ';' token` but `*(*(arr + 1) + 1));` prints `3`

Comment: @dave `*(*(arr + 2))` works properly for me.  You're probably missing a closing brace for your `printf` call.  Also, `*(*(arr + 1) + 1))` is choosing a different array element which happens to have the same value as the one you're attempting to print.  `arr[2][0]` and `arr[1][1]` both contain the value 3.

Answer (score 3):

`arr` is an array of arrays of `int`. On almost any use an array is converted to a pointer to its first element. So `arr` gets converted to a pointer to an array of `int`.

OK, `arr` gets converted to a pointer to an array of `int`, so `(arr+2)` is of the same type, that is, a pointer to an array of `int`.

Now `*(arr+2)` is the thing `(arr+2)` points to. That is, an array of `int`.

Now since it's an array of `int`, it gets converted to a pointer to its first element. So  `*(arr+2)` gets converted to a pointer to `int`. Note it is *not* an `int` and is unlikely to be equal to `3`.

Now how come `(arr+2)` and `*(arr+2)` dosplay the same? They are a pointer to an array and a pointer to its first element. Although these pointets are of different types, they represent the same address, because the address of any array is the same as the address of its first element.

Answer (score 1):

`arr` is the pointer to the first array of the type `int[2]`.`(arr + 2)` is the pointer to the third such array.
Whereas `*(arr + 2)` is the pointer to the first element of the `(arr +2)` array.

Both of these will hence have the same address since they are pointing to the same position.The only difference being in their type.`(arr+2)` is of the type `int(*)[2]` whereas `*(arr + 2)` is of the type `int *`.