# what is the difference between int and int * in C

Tags: c, ubuntu

i'm trying to compile a function to populate a matrix with zeros and ones as part of an adjacency matrix assignment but i keep getting errors when i use the make comma

this is the function that i have in a populateMat.c file.

```
#include "defs.h"
void PopulateMat(adjmat *mat[N][N]){

printf("\n the matrix size is [%d] x [%d]\n please enter connections between nodes.\n", N,N);
int i;
int j;
for ( i = 0; i < N ;i++){
    for ( j = 0; j < N ;j++)
    {
        printf("\n is there a connection between node %d to node %d ?\n yes - 1 \n no - 0\n", i, j);
        scanf("%d", mat[i][j]);
        if (!(&mat[i][j]==0 || (int)&mat[i][j]==1)) {
            printf("\n%d",mat[i][j]);
            printf("wrong indication inserted.\n insert 1 for yes \n 0 for no ");
            j--;
        }
    }
}
```

}

and this is the error when i run `gcc -Wall -ansi -pedantic populateMat.c`

```
populateMat.c: In function ‘PopulateMat’:
populateMat.c:13:19: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int *’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)[3][3]’ [-Wformat=]
             scanf("%d", mat[i][j]);
                   ^
populateMat.c:15:24: warning: format ‘%d’ expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 2 has type ‘int (*)[3][3]’ [-Wformat=]
                 printf("\n%d",mat[i][j]);
                        ^
/usr/lib/gcc/i686-linux-gnu/5/../../../i386-linux-gnu/crt1.o: In function `_start':
(.text+0x18): undefined reference to `main'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

my main.c is

```
int main()
{
    adjmat mat;                                    // defined in defs.h 
    typedef int adjmat [N][N];
    PopulateMat(&mat);
    printf("adjacency matrix received");
    // הדפסת מטריצת שכנויות
    printMat(mat);
    adjacency(&mat);
    return 0;
}
```

and Clion is giving this warning about populateMat(&mat)
**
incompatible pointer types passing 'adjmat *' (aka 'int (*)[3][3]') to parameter of type 'adjmat *(*)[3]'
**
i've been trying to figure it out for way to long,
help!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Correct format specifier to print pointer or address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-or-address)

Comment: You really should update the question title.

Comment: i read it but i still cant understand what i did wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your `scanf("%d", mat[i][j]);`: should be like this in for loop,
 `scanf("%d", &mat[i][j]);`

Function definition :
`void PopulateMat(adjmat *mat, N)`

If statement code should look like this :
`if (!(mat[i][j]==0 || mat[i][j]==1))`
**No need to use & after**`||`

Answer (score 0):

The `typedef` used to create an alias name for other data type. This statement

```
    typedef int adjmat [N][N];
```

creates `adjmat` an alias of `int [N][N]` type.

In this

```
void PopulateMat(adjmat *mat[N][N]){
```

the type of function parameter `mat` is `adjmat *mat[N][N]`, that means `mat` is of type `adjmat *(*)[N]` which is equivalent to `int (*(*)[N])[N][N]`.
In `main()`, you are passing `&mat` as argument to `PopulateMat()`. The type of `&mat` is `adjmat *` which is equivalent `int (*)[N][N]`.
The type of argument passed to `PopulateMat()` and type of parameter of `PopulateMat()` is not matching, hence you are getting incompatible type warning on this statement - `PopulateMat(&mat);`.

You should correct the type of `PopulateMat()` function parameter `mat`. It should be `adjmat *`:

```
void PopulateMat(adjmat *mat) {
 ....
 ....
```

the `adjmat *mat` is equivalent to `int (*mat)[N][N]`.

With this, you can access the `i`<sup>th</sup> row and `j`<sup>th</sup> column like this `(*mat)[i][j]`.
Note that `scanf()` expects pointer as argument. So, for taking input to `i`<sup>th</sup> row and `j`<sup>th</sup> column of `mat`, do this

```
scanf("%d", &(*mat)[i][j]);
```

---

Instead of passing address of `mat` to `PopulateMat()` function, you can pass `mat` as well because an array decays to pointer (with few exceptions).

So, you can also do

```
PopulateMat(mat);
```

and, in this case, the prototype of `Populate()` should be

```
void PopulateMat(adjmat mat);
```

here the type of `mat` is `int (*)[N]` (array to pointer decay only happen for inner most dimension).

With this, in the `Populate()` function, you can access the `i`<sup>th</sup> row and `j`<sup>th</sup> column of `mat` like this `mat[i][j]`.

Hope this helps.