# Python <__main__.class object at 0x107857490>

Tags: python-3.x

I am looking for resources on how python uses the address representation found when printing an instance object <**main**.class object at 0x107857490>.

My guess is that this can't be a hardware address as I know that even C does not represent hardware address in code and instead simply gives you pointers that represent addresses in the C runtime.

Are there resources on implementation details in python like this?

Comment: Assuming CPython, this is almost certainly just the value of the C pointer to the Python object. But, I'll see if I can find out for sure. What are you trying to do with this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll assume you're asking about the CPython implementation in particular.

In the [CPython Github repo](https://github.com/python/cpython), the file `Objects/object.c` seems to have our answer. On [line 390](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/object.c#L390) is defined the function `PyObject_Repr(PyObject *v)`, which, after some checks, has the following code:

```
    if (Py_TYPE(v)->tp_repr == NULL)
        return PyUnicode_FromFormat("<%s object at %p>",
                                    Py_TYPE(v)->tp_name, v);
```

which reads to me as follows:

```
    // If the Python object v does not have a custom __repr__
    if (Py_TYPE(v)->tp_repr == NULL)

        // then return '<' + name_of_type + ' object at ' + v + '>'
        return PyUnicode_FromFormat("<%s object at %p>",
                                    Py_TYPE(v)->tp_name, v);
```

Assuming that `PyUnicode_FromFormat` uses the same syntax as `printf`, then [`%p` gives the value of the pointer `v`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-or-address).