# Why is the length of address of variable only 6 digits in hex code although my machine is 64 bit?

Tags: c, pointers, memory, memory-address

When I tried printing out address of variable in C to my standard output in hexadecimal format, I got a 6 digit answer to my surprise. Since, I work on a 64 bit machine, I expected to have a 16 digit long address since `2^{64} = 16^{16}` but instead the address was just 6 digits long.

Code for reference:

```
#include<stdio.h>

int square();

int x;

int main(){
    scanf("%d",&x);
    printf("%d\n",square());
    printf("\naddress of x is %x",&x);
    return 0;
}

int square(){
    return x*x;
}
```

The output was:
`address of x is 407970`

Comment: Because the leading digits are zero? And because `%x` is only using 32 bits? Use `%p` for an address.

Comment: Did you mean to print `sizeof(int)`, `sizeof(void*)`, or `sizeof(uintptr_t)` instead?

Comment: `%x` expects `unsigned int`

Comment: `printf("\naddress of x is %x", &x);` -> `printf("\naddress of x is %p", (void*)&x);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all `printf("\naddress of x is %x",&x);` is incorrect. `%x` expects an `unsigned int`.

The correct format specifier to print address is `%p` ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-or-address)):

```
printf("\naddress of x is %p",&x);

//To be more precise cast to void*, see @Gerhardh's comment below
printf("\naddress of x is %p", (void*)&x);
```

> Why is the length of address of variable only 6 digits in hex code although my machine is 64 bit?

```
unsigned long x = 10;
printf("%lu", x); //prints 10
```

`x` is 10 in the above example. Does it mean `x` is now 8 bit wide? No. Similarly there is a range of addresses starting from 0, the address doesn't have to be big enough to be represented as full 64 bit always. You can assume it to be `0x00407970` in your case.

---

**Side note:** The following will have undefined behaviour *if* the value of `x` is large. Just enter `123123` as input and see what happens

```
int square(){
    return x*x;
}
```

Comment: To be more precise, `%p` expects to get a `void` pointer. You should cast the parameter to `(void *)` when passing to `printf`. Without a proper parameter list, no implicit conversion of the pointer will happen.