# Erro expects argument of type ‘int’, but argument 3 has type ‘int *’

Tags: c, pointers, compiler-errors, printf, conversion-specifier

I'm trying to compile and display the address of each value into the arrays.

```
int i[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}, x;
float f[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
double d[10] = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

/*int *p_i = &i;                                                             
                                                                             
float *p_f = &f;                                                             
                                                                             
double *p_d = &d;*/

int main(void){
  printf("\n\tInteger\tFloat\tDouble");
  printf("\n=======================================");

  /* loop to show the address in each element that have the arrayes */
  for(x = 0; x < 10; x++){
    printf("\nElement %d\t%d\t%d\t%d", x+1, &i[x], &f[x], &d[x]);
    // printf("\nElement %d\t%d\t%d\t%d", x+1, p_i++, p_f++, p_d++);         
  }
  printf("\n=======================================\n");
}
```

I don't understand why if the syntax is right. Also I have search and the found code is almost the same.

Comment: Change `%d` to `%p` for the pointers.

Comment: `i[x]` is an `int`.  `&i[x]` is a pointer to that `int`. If the `int` is what you want to print, then that's what you should pass to `printf()`.  If the pointer is what you want to print then the correct directive is `%p`, not `%d`.  Similar applies even more so for variables `f` and `d`: if you want to print the `float` and `double` then the corresponding directives should (both) be `%f`, and you should not use `&`.  If you want to print the pointers then the directive should be `%p`.

Comment: And don't forget to cast pointers to `void*`: `printf("\nElement %d\t%d\t%d\t%d", x+1, &i[x], &f[x], &d[x]);` -> `printf("\nElement %d\t%p\t%p\t%p", x+1, (void*)&i[x], (void*)&f[x], (void*)&d[x]);`

Comment: See [Correct format specifier to print pointer or address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9053658/1275169)

Comment: ButchBet, Do you want to print an `int` or a pointer?

Answer (score 1):

You are using incorrect conversion specifiers.

The conversion specifier `%d` expects an argument of the type `int` while you are supplying arguments of pointer types.

Instead of

```
printf("\nElement %d\t%d\t%d\t%d", x+1, &i[x], &f[x], &d[x]);
```

write

```
printf( "\nElement %d\t%p\t%p\t%p", 
        x+1, ( void * )&i[x], ( void * )&f[x], ( void * )&d[x] );
```

or

```
printf( "\nElement %d\t%p\t%p\t%p", 
        x+1, ( void * )( i + x ), ( void * )(f + x ), ( void * )( d + x ) );
```