# %d vs %f format specifier (not sure of output): C

Tags: c, format-specifiers

I get that %d is the format specifier for type decimal, and %f is for float, but I'm not sure why the output of the 2nd print statement is 3.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    float arr[5] = {12.5, 10.0, 13.5, 90.5, 0.5};
    float *ptr1 = &arr[0];
    float *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;
 
    printf("%f ", *ptr2);
    printf("%d", ptr2 - ptr1);
 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: ptr2 = ptr1 + 3;

Comment: I would encourage you to consider using the `%p` format specifier for pointers: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9053835/421195.  To answer your question: the value of "ptr2 - ptr1" is simply "3" :)

Comment: But the correct modifier for `ptrdiff_t` (which is the result of subtracting two pointers) is `t` — as in `%td` to print the difference between two pointers as a decimal integer.

Comment: @paulsm4 appreciate the advice :). I was doing a geeksforgeeks quiz and was a bit confused by this. I think I'm not understanding pointers. I get that abstractly "ptr2 - ptr1" is 3 because that's how many indexes are between the two, but in my head I am saying "The address that ptr2 points to - the address that ptr1 points to" and when I think of it like that I'm not really sure how I would come up with 3.

Comment: Pointer arithmetic in C is scaled by the size of the object pointed at.  Adding `3` to a `float *` adds `3 * sizeof(float)` to the byte address.  To see the difference, consider using `printf("%td\n", (char *)ptr2 - (char *) ptr1)` as well — the answer should be `12`.  You could also use `printf("ptr1 = %p\nptr2 = %p\n", (void *)ptr1, (void *)ptr2);` to see the byte addresses.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Ok now I'm starting to understand. Those print statements you provided really helped. Although now I have a question about those pointer castings you did. What is the purpose of (char *) and (void *)? How does casting a float to a char pointer give you bytes? Also when I tried printing just "(char *)ptr2" I got a really wacky number.

Comment: `ptr1` is a `float *` — a pointer to a `float`.  Converting the type to `char *` is a no-op on most modern machines (but was not a no-op on the machine where I learned to program C!); it simply tells the compiler to treat the address as a `char *`, so that the size of what the cast address points to is `1` (aka `sizeof(char)`).  The `%p` format specifier formats the address for a `void *`, so the casts there ensure that the type passed to `printf()` is of the correct type.

Comment: Also, %f is double not float.

Comment: "%d is the format specifier for type decimal, "  --> No.  `"%d"` matches type `int` to print as decimal text.  For pointer subtraction the resultant type is `ptrdiff_t` which matches `"%td"`,

Comment: @OkCloudy - if this doesn't explain why you should stay well away from geeksforgeek, nothing will. Avoid so-called programming sites. Many are just plain wrong and contain horrible coding practices. Stack Overflow provides [The Definitive C Book Guide and List](https://stackoverflow.com/q/562303/3422102) to help facilitate just this type of learning. Well worth picking up a proper reference.

Answer (score 2):

So, you seem to have pointer arithmetic mostly down, since you understand why `*ptr2` equals 90.5, but you're missing a piece here. You have to remember that `ptr1` and `ptr2` on their own refer to memory addresses - which are integers - and not the floating point numbers stored at those addresses. The difference of addresses `ptr2` and `ptr1` is 3, as you set in the line `float *ptr2 = ptr1 + 3`.

---

I can't tell exactly what your goal is here, but if you are trying to print an integer of the difference of the floats *stored at* those addresses (which I think you are), you'll need to dereference the pointers and perform a type cast. The final line before `return 0` should be `printf("%d", (int)(*ptr2 - *ptr1))`. This prints `78` to the console.

But, that's only if the "assignment" here is to specifically use an integer. Realistically, it would be written more like `printf("%0.f", *ptr2 - *ptr1)`, which keeps the number as a float but will not print anything after the decimal point.