# Trouble understanding char* and string in CS50

Tags: c, cs50, implicit-conversion, string-literals, pointer-arithmetic

So I know that a string is just an array of characters that are stored consecutively in a computer's memory.

I also know that in order to find out the location of a string, you just have to go to the location of the first character as its consecutive and the string ends when the program or function encounters the \0 character.

But what I don't understand is :

1. ```
   char* s = "HI!";
   ```

Does it create an array of 4 characters? Or is it just a pointer pointing to the starting character location? Or is it doing both?

2.

```
    char* name = "BEN";
    printf("%c %c\n", *(name + 1), *name + 1);
```

Why do they both give two different outputs (E and C), instead of both giving E?

Comment: "Does it create an array of 4 characters?" --> "It", the compiler, forms a `char[4]` with the string `"HI!"` in it.  `s` gets the address of the first element.  Need more than that?

Comment: number 2 is a classic case of [operator precedence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence)

Comment: `"HI!"` by itself is an array of 4 characters. `char* s` then points to its first element.

Comment: King Brain, Why do you expect `'B' + 1` to give `'E'`?

Comment: Ah i see....the compiler does it automatically huh. What about the 2nd question? Also is there a way to print the address of the pointer itself?

Comment: To print the address of any object, convert the object address to `void *` and use `"%p"`: `printf("%p\n", (void*) &object);`.

Comment: I see so thats why its printing C....thanks a lot for the info.

Comment: (void*)name and *name, in printf, both give me the address of B. Is it possible to get the address of the pointer that is holding the address of B?

Comment: `(void *)&name` is the address of the `name` variable.

Comment: *"I know that a string is just an array of characters that are stored consecutively in a computer's memory."* In your previous questions, it has been said that the distinction between an array of characters and a string, is that the latter ends with a `0` or `'\0'` element. Without that it is only an array, not the special case of string.

Comment: See [Correct format specifier to print pointer or address?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9053658/15168)

Comment: Note that the `cs50.h` header includes `typedef char *string;` — a controversial decision.  Your question doesn't really ask about this, though.  The references to "string" seem to be to the generic concept defined in the C standard [§7.1.1 Definitions of terms ¶1](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.1.1p1) rather than to the typedef in the `cs50.h` header.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I suspect that OP now understands from their previous questions that `string` is a cs50 invention (supposed convenience). To King Brain: I did not do cs50, but at first I did find it helpful with more complicated syntax to `typedef` a pointer. Later I understood why it isn't helpful, see [Is it a good idea to typedef pointers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750178/is-it-a-good-idea-to-typedef-pointers)

Comment: Thanks a lot for all the advice. Just wanted to ask one last thing....if char* name = "Ben'; does printf("%p", &name); print the address of the pointer itself? Cuz i was getting two different addresses with and without the & in front of name

Comment: The variable `name` is a pointer, so `printf("%p", &name);` would show where the pointer is *stored* (a pointer to a pointer haha) , but `printf("%p", name);` shows the pointer. More properly, it should be `printf("%p", (void*)name);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this declaration

```
char* s = "HI!";
```

Two entities are created.

The first one is the string literal `"HI!"` which has static storage duration  and array type `char[4]`. (In C++ it has constant character array type `const char[4]`, in opposite to C.)

You can check this using printf

```
printf( "sizeof( \"HI!\" ) = %zu\n", sizeof( "HI!" ) );
```

Here the character array is used as an initializer of the pointer `s`. In this case it is implicitly converted to the first element of a pointer and the pointer `s` points to the address of the first element of the array.

As for this code snippet

```
char* name = "BEN";
printf("%c %c\n", *(name + 1), *name + 1);
```

The expression `name + 1` has type `char *` and points to the second character of the string literal `"BEN"` (thus `'E'`), due to the pointer arithmetic. Dereferencing the pointer expression like `*(name + 1)` you get the symbol of the string literal pointed to by the expression. Actually, the expression `*(name + 1)` is the same as `name[1]` that is the same as `1[name]`.:)

As for this expression `*name`, dereferencing the pointer `name` you get the first symbol `'B'` of the string literal. Then, 1 is added to the internal code of the symbol `( *name + 1 ), so the expression takes the value of the next symbol after` 'B'`, which is` 'C'`. The expression` ( *name + 1 )`is equivalent to the expression`name[0] + 1`.

Using the subscript operator like `name[1]` and `name[0] + 1` makes the expressions more clear.

I think it would be interesting for you to know that the call of `printf` may be rewritten using only the original string literal. Some examples:

```
printf("%c %c\n", *( "BEN" + 1), *"BEN" + 1);
```

or

```
printf("%c %c\n", "BEN"[1], "BEN"[0] + 1);
```

or even

```
printf("%c %c\n", 1["BEN"], 0["BEN"] + 1);
```

Answer (score 2):

> But what I don't understand is :
>
> `char* s = "HI!";`
>
> Does it create an array of 4 characters? Or is it just a pointer pointing to the starting character location? Or is it doing both?

The right side of the assignment, `= "HI!";` provisions a constant array of chars (4 including the null character). Where/how the memory is allocated for these 4 chars is not of concern. The compiler is free to choose where `"HI!"` lives and how long it lives for.

The left side of the assignment: `char *s =`  declares a local pointer on the stack to point to the first character of the array (the `'H'`)

> `char* name = "BEN";`
>
> `printf("%c %c\n", *(name + 1), *name + 1);`
>
> Why do they both give two different outputs (E and C), instead of both giving E?

- `name` is a pointer. It points to the address of the letter `B` in that string.
- `name+1` is a pointer to one character past `B` in that string, in this case, `E`.
- `*name` is the value held at the address pointed to by `name`. In other words the character `'B'`.
- `*name + 1` is the same as `(*name) + 1` or `'B' + 1` or `'C'`. You're adding 1 to the value, not the address in this expression.
- `*(name + 1)`, evaluates to the second character in the string referenced by `name`. Or `'E'` as you might expect

Answer (score 1):

1. In `char* s = "HI!";` then `"HI!"` is a *string literal*. `s` points at the `H`. The string literal is 4 `char` long (including the terminating `\0`). Another (non-idiomatic) way to look at it:

   ```c
   char(*s)[4] = &"HI!";
   ```

   ... and here `s` is a pointer to a `char[4]`.
2. In your second example, it's about in which order you do things, the operator precedence.

   ```c
   char* name = "BEN";
   printf("%c %c\n", *(name + 1), *name + 1);
   ```

   - `(name + 1)` adds `1` to the `char*` `name` so you get a pointer pointing at the `E`. After that you *dereference* the pointer with `*` and get `E`.
   - `*name` dereferences the pointer, which points at `B` and then you `+ 1` to it, making it `C`.

It's the same as doing this:

```c
printf("%c %c\n", name[1], name[0] + 1);
```