# How to write out a numeric value using low-level C

Tags: c

i have a task where i need to pass a pointer to my function and display it in my function with "write".

```c
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void ft_ft(int *nbr){
    //printf("%d\n", *nbr);
    char c = *nbr;

    write(1, &c, 1);

}

int main(){
    int nbr = 42;
    ft_ft(&nbr);
}
```

as you can see i tried to make a int value into a char as taking the pointer from the parameter wouldn't work. on the other hand this doesn't either so could you help me?

the error msg:

> [Running] (((the folder its in))) && gcc (((name of file)))...
> OUTPUT: *
> [Done] exited with code=0 in 0.046 seconds

so it actually ran the code but its not the output i would have wanted, what am i missing?

> the printf() works fine but i can't get "write" to work.

thanks in advance

Comment: PSA: Remember, `fputc` exists if that's your intent here. If you're trying to show the (raw) value of the pointer, then [use `%p`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-or-address).

Comment: it was demanded of me by my school, and now im invested to find the answer cuz its bugging me :)

Comment: It'd be good to know what you're expecting the output to be here. There are many interpretations given what you've said and shown.

Comment: i simply want to output the "42" from main(), it works with printf() but not the write()....why?

Comment: So, which output does your assignment require? The ASCII value (i.e. `printf("%d\n",*nbr);`) or (as tadman said) the _binary_ value of 42, which is 0x2A, which is `*`?

Comment: @CraigEstey the ASCII one, i want the output to be "42" straight

Comment: To use `write`, try: `void ft_ft(int *nbr) { char buf[100]; size_t len = sprintf(buf,"%d\n",*nbr); write(1, buf, len); }`

Comment: You'll need to convert your character to its ASCII decimal representation if you want to use the very low-level `write` call. It *expects* the *exact* characters being written. I'm not sure if you're expected to do this conversion yourself, but consider a loop where you emit `(n % 10) + '0'` and then `n /= 10` to shift to the next digit. Of course this will be in reverse order, so you may need to capture it into a buffer and flip it around.

Comment: thx for the help imma try it out guys

Comment: @CraigEstey how can i mark your comment as the answer ^^?

Comment: thx 4 the help everyone :D!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> @CraigEstey how can i mark your comment as the answer ^? –
> 7Ver7dict7

Okay, here is the answer. To use `write` instead of `printf`, we can use `snprintf` and then `write`:

```
void
ft_ft(int *nbr)
{
    char buf[100];
    size_t len = snprintf(buf, sizeof buf, "%d\n", *nbr);
    write(1, buf, len);
}
```

In the event that any `snprinf` and related functions are also unacceptable, the following solution may suit:

```
void
ft_ft(int *nbr)
{
    char buf[100];

    // point past the end
    char *end = &buf[sizeof(buf)];

    // last valid place for a char
    char *beg = end - 1;

    // add newline to end
    *beg-- = '\n';

    // get copy
    int num = *nbr;

    // special case for zero
    if (num == 0)
        *beg-- = '0';

    // handle negative numbers
    int neg = (num < 0);
    if (neg)
        num = -num;

    // add digits from least significant to most significant
    for (;  num != 0;  num /= 10) {
        int dig = num % 10;
        *beg-- = dig + '0';
    }

    // add in minus sign
    if (neg)
        *beg-- = '-';

    // point to first char
    ++beg;

    // output final string
    write(1, beg, end - beg);
}
```

Comment: instead of size write len in"write(1, buf, size/len)"

Comment: @7Ver7dict7 Yup. When I posted the comment, I fixed it on the fly. But, the error was still in the `.c` file -- fixed now.

Comment: @Clifford I consider your entire comment to be completely wrong and offensive. See my update as to why.

Comment: Since you offered a solution that addresses my concern, I have removed the comment.  I have also removed all references to the comment in your answer (really not cool).  I think you misunderstood.  It was intended as advice to the OP that if they submitted that as a solution to an assignment, there is a possibility that it may follow the letter but not the spirit of the assignment.