# Pointers from Python code to C library functions are truncated to 32 bits

Tags: python

As indicated in the title the pointer I'm passing from Python to a C shared library is being truncated to 32-bits. I discovered this with a fairly large library. The code that is in the library has been used in 5 different sets of test code so I'm confident in the code but in all cases it has been integrated into the test code and not as a shared library. With my real code I was getting segmentation faults when I used the pointer. When I comment out the line that used the pointer the segmentation fault goes away. I've recreated the truncation problem using the simplest case I could think of - one function in a library that takes a pointer as an input and doesn't return a value. Just for background, I'm a Python newbie but have developed C code applications and embedded firmware for 30+ years and this is my first time creating a shared library.

Below are the simple case C code first and then the Python code. I've left out the .h files declarations and imports for brevity.

C code:

```
void ptr_test(uint32_t *ptr)
{
    printf("ptr_test: ptr =  0x%x\n", ptr);
}
```

Python code:

```
PTR_TEST = ctypes.CDLL('./libptr_test.so')
ptr_test = PTR_TEST.ptr_test
ptr_test.restype = None
ptr_test.argtypes = [POINTER(c_uint32)]

tbuf1 = np.empty((1,1), dtype=c_uint32)             # force a single 32-bit integer
print("tbuf1 at 0x{:02X}" .format((tbuf1.ctypes.data)))

ptr_test(tbuf1[0].ctypes.data_as(POINTER(c_uint32)))

del(PTR_TEST)
exit()
```

As you can see in the output below the C code only gets the low 32-bits of the address:
tbuf1 at 0x561ED7289E60
ptr_test: ptr =  0xd7289e60

The posts in various forums about this issue all seemed to be resolved by setting argtypes (or just spelling it correctly). Also, the type of pointer doesn't make any difference. I've also tried void pointers and the original code uses a pointer to a structure.

I'm doing this on a 64-bit system using Ubuntu 22.04, gcc 11.4 under Eclipse and Python 3.10.12. I thought I might accidentally be generating a 32-bit library file but it actually takes quite a bit of gyrating to do that. I'm not ruling out there being a problem with the library file. I have not tested the library file with a C program but will do that in the next day or two. Also, I came across PyBind11 yesterday. I'm willing to give it a try but have a lot of time invested in using ctypes and I'm hoping I'm over-looking something simple that will make it work.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated. I'm about 16 hours into chasing this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9053658/correct-format-specifier-to-print-pointer-or-address

Comment: Try `%p` format string instead of `%x`

Comment: Wow! Thanks Mat and Dan. I've never had to do that. So much for 30 years experience.

Comment: If my pointer was actually correct then why was it causing a Seg fault? Does the library code have access to memory used in the Python code or do I need to use shared memory between them?